# Convert 00:45:00 to 0.45 or 01:45:00 to 1.45 from date difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i  convert 00:45:00 to 0.45 or 01:45:00 to 1.45  from date dfifference. I used below query

```
select cast(datepart(hour, '01:45:00')+datepart(minute, '01:45:00') / 100.00 as decimal(7,4));
```

but when not get exact result same as above in difference

select `cast(datediff(HOUR,'00:00:00','01:45:00')+datediff(minute,'00:00:00','01:45:00') / 100.00 as decimal(7,4));`

Comment: By 1.45, do you mean a decimal number? 1:45 is 1hour plus 3/4 of one, so maybe is should be 1.75

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first answer appears to be what you want.

If you break apart the second expression, you will find that:

```
datediff(minute,'00:00:00','01:45:00')
```

evaluates to 105 and not 45.

If you want to use arithmetic on the dateparts, just use minutes:

```
cast(datediff(minute,'00:00:00','01:45:00') / 60 +
     (datediff(minute,'00:00:00','01:45:00') % 60 / 100.0
     ) as decimal(7, 4)
    )
```